# Overflow hidden only at the top (y)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I got an owl carousel that cuts off part of some ribbons I attached to each item. Figured out it had to do with `overflow:hidden` which the plugin attaches around all items. So I thought I could easily fix this by using:

```
overflow-x:hidden;
overflow-y:visible;
```

Except it doesn't work, when I change one to visible and one to hidden, they are both visible.

Example:

How they are at the moment:

[image]

How I want the ribbons to be, and when I add the above code (notice how everything is visible):
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you load your own CSS after owl caourel's CSS?

Comment: try to adding some padding in `#owl-demo .item`

Comment: @MinalChauhan Thanks that worked, still weird why only hiding one side with overflow is not working.